# Facebook SDK, GraphUser user is always null

Tags: android, facebook

No matter what I try, Facebook GraphUser user is alsways null. I am trying the following using Facebook SDK 3.23.0

```
 loginButton
        .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                FragmentFour.this.user = user;

                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d("Name",user.getName());
                } else {
                    Log.d("Name","Not Logged in!!");
                }

            }
        });
```

I have done with hash key and have successfully experimented Facebook samples in Facebook SDK using own created app id. But whenever I try above code i always get user as null. Please help.

Comment: Why negative vote, I didn't understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself by adding

```
loginBtn.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
loginBtn.setFragment(this);
```